# SQL: Select statement to return ratio of 2 column values

Tags: sql

I have a table of electronic testing data containing pass/fail results for pairs of components at given voltages. It looks like this:

```
Component_A|Component_B|Voltage|Result
1           2           1.0     Pass
1           2           1.0     Pass
1           2           1.0     Fail
1           2           1.0     Fail
1           2           2.0     Pass
1           2           2.0     Pass
1           2           2.0     Pass
1           2           2.0     Pass
3           4           1.0     Pass
3           4           1.0     Pass
3           4           1.0     Pass
3           4           1.0     Pass
3           4           2.0     Pass
3           4           2.0     Pass
3           4           2.0     Pass
3           4           2.0     Pass
```

For each `Component_A`, `Component_B`, `Voltage`, I'd like to show the failure ratio for the given `Component_A/Component_B/Voltage` combination as well as the failure ratio for that combination of `Component_A/Component_B`. The expected output would be as follows:

```
Component_A|Component_B|Voltage|Voltage_Fail_Ratio|Component_Fail_Ratio
1           2           1.0     2/4(0.5)            2/8(0.25)
1           2           2.0     0/4(0)              0/8(0)
3           4           1.0     4/4(0)              0/8(0)
3           4           2.0     0/4(0)              0/8(0)
```

It would be great to have some options (using unions or subqueries... the more options the better). I've tried a writing a subquery to at least get the voltage_fail_ratio, but it doesn't report component/voltage combos with no failures and I am not sure how to get the component_fail ratio:

```
SELECT f.component_a,f.component_b,f.voltage,f.failcount,p.passcount, f.failcount/(f.failcount+p.passcount) FROM 
 ((SELECT component_a,component_b,voltage, count(*) as failcount from `tests` where 
  result='FAIL' 
 GROUP BY component_a,component_b,voltage) f INNER JOIN  
 (SELECT component_a,component_b,voltage, count(*) as passcount from `tests` where 
  result='PASS' 
 GROUP BY component_a,component_b,voltage) p on p.component_a=f.component_a and p.component_b=f.component_b and 
 p.voltage=f.voltage);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/623ae/1

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want - it computes the `Voltage_Fail_Ratio` and `Component_Fail_Ratio` in two separate subqueries that are then joined on matching `component_a` and `component_b` values:

```
SELECT t1.component_a, t1.component_b, t1.Voltage, t1.Voltage_Fail_Ratio, Component_Fail_Ratio
FROM (
  SELECT component_a, component_b, Voltage,
         SUM(result = 'FAIL') / COUNT(*) AS Voltage_Fail_Ratio
  FROM tests
  GROUP BY component_a, component_b, Voltage
  ) t1
JOIN (
  SELECT component_a, component_b,
         SUM(result = 'FAIL') / COUNT(*) AS Component_Fail_Ratio
  FROM tests
  GROUP BY component_a, component_b
  ) t2 ON t2.component_a = t1.component_a AND t2.component_b = t1.component_b
;
```

Output:

```
component_a     component_b     Voltage     Voltage_Fail_Ratio  Component_Fail_Ratio
1               2               1           0.5                 0.25
1               2               2           0                   0.25
3               4               1           0                   0
3               4               2           0                   0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/623ae/7)

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow similar with @Nick's but using views with WITH.
Just to give you more option.

```
WITH for_volt_fail_ratio AS(
  SELECT com_a, com_b, volt, SUM(result = 'FAIL') / COUNT(*) AS Voltage_Fail_Ratio
  FROM tests
  GROUP BY com_a, com_b, volt),
 for_com_fail_ratio AS(
  SELECT com_a, com_b,SUM(result = 'FAIL') / COUNT(*) AS Component_Fail_Ratio
  FROM tests
  GROUP BY com_a, com_b),
 sh AS(
   SELECT tb1.com_a,tb1.com_b,tb1.volt,tb1.Voltage_Fail_Ratio,tb2.Component_Fail_Ratio
   FROM for_volt_fail_ratio tb1 INNER JOIN for_com_fail_ratio tb2 ON (tb1.com_a=tb2.com_a AND tb1.com_b=tb2.com_b)
  )
 SELECT * FROM sh
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3a3caa7218714a4e86181d0ce689b1e)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is conditional aggregation:

```
select component_a, component_b, voltage,
        sum(case when result = 'PASS' then 1 else 0 end) as num_pass,
        sum(case when result = 'FAIL' then 1 else 0 end) as num_fail,
        avg(case when result = 'FAIL' then 1.0 else 0 end) as fail_rate
from tests
group by component_a, component_b, voltage;
```

If you are indeed using MySQL (as the SQL Fiddle suggests), you can simplify this to:

```
select component_a, component_b, voltage,
        sum(result = 'PASS') as num_pass,
        sum(result = 'FAIL') as num_fail,
        avg(result = 'FAIL') as fail_rate
from tests
group by component_a, component_b, voltage
```